# SICK Scanner PLS200-113

Tags: ros, laserscanner, sick, sicktoolbox-wrapper

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I'm currently trying to get the SICK PLS200 Laserscanner to work. Unfortunately I'm not able to do it.
The ROS provided sicktoolbox_wrapper does only support LMS200, LMS291 right?
Because I'm getting an error following the tutorial.

So my question is:

Does someone already worked with the SICK PLS200 under ROS and where can i find a working solution for it?

I would be happy about some help

Best Regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61600/sick-scanner-pls200-113/) by [Tirgo](https://answers.ros.org/users/2060/tirgo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2013-04-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here you go. Modified LMS drivers to support PLS range laser. https://github.com/hawesie/laser_drivers/tree/master/sicktoolbox_pls_wrapper. Haven't tried it yet, cuz I'm having troubles with rviz.

---

Originally posted by [TonyGon](https://answers.ros.org/users/3224/tonygon/) with karma: 41 on 2013-04-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1